# GeoServer layer security: How to remove rights for a single layer?

Tags: geoserver, security

I am using **GeoServer 2.19.2**

Following the documentation on *https://docs.geoserver.org/2.19.x/en/user/security/layer.html* I try to remove rights for every layer in a specific workspace.

I have the impression that removing rights only applies to layergroups, but not to individual layers.

**Initial situation:**

I have two workspaces:

- Workspace 'Germany' contains 20 layers and a layergroup 'AllGermany' where the layergroup conatins all 20 layers of the workspace
- Workspace 'Spain' contains 100 layers and a layergroup 'AllSpain' where the layergroup conatins all 100 layers of the workspace

**Configuration:**

To remove ALL rights for everyone, I set the following into 'layer.properties':

mode=MIXED

*.*.r=NO_ONE

**Result:**

Requesting a **WORKSPACE** via *https://SERVER/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=Germany:AllGermany&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&VERSION=1.1.1&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=959933.59249998,6389579.12,960123.95749998,6389666.48&WIDTH=2719&HEIGHT=1248*
**leads - as expected - to HTTP Status 403 (Access Denied)**.

But requesting a **single layer within a WORKSPACE** via *https://SERVER/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=Germany:layer1&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&VERSION=1.1.1&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=959933.59249998,6389579.12,960123.95749998,6389666.48&WIDTH=2719&HEIGHT=1248*
**works and returns the image**.

Is it correct that setting rights only affects layergroups and not single layers or is there an error?

**UPDATE:** Updated GeoServer from 2.19.2 to 2.22.0 --> same problem here!

Comment: editing `layer.properties` is almost certainly the wrong way to do it, use the GUI or the REST API

Comment: Thanks but this is not the point. Setting permissions by the GUI has the same effect in layers.properties and so the same effect as described above.

Comment: would it depend on the type of layer group you have: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html?highlight=group